# tkinter tkMessageBox html link

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I got a tkMEssagebox.showerror showing up in a python tkinter application,
when somebody failed to login with the application.
Is it possible to have a url link in the tkMessageBox.showerror?

ie.

> tkMessageBox.showerror("Error","An error occured please visit
>   www.blahblubbbb.com")

and I want the www.blahblubbbb.com to be clickable?!

Comment: Hey, your question got me curious, so I wrote up a quick prototype of a hyperlink messagebox. I've put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/u0Z3CdtX. Not very complete, but it should give you an idea of what to do should you decide to roll your own.

Comment: awesome Joel ... thanks for the work! I've saved a copy of it on my gist if its ok with you cause I always lose pastebin links :-) https://gist.github.com/4130284

Comment: as of this http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/cursors.htm the cursor on Enter has to be either hand1 or hand2 :-)

Comment: @JoelCornett: Very nice! Why don't post it as an answer? Wouldn't mind your answer getting picked! ;-)

Comment: @JoelCornett Thats so nice. I will suggest you the set the border `bd` of the text to 0 so there is no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: "No!" message is a simple string, no interpretation like in some widgets of other frameworks is done.

Longer answer: You could e.g. subclass+monkeypatch, to provide such feature.